# Problema al Enviar datos Json mediante AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Saludos , estoy empezando a utilizar la tecnología ajax para enviar datos tipo JSON a una hoja php para realizar un insert a la base de datos,en un login de facebook  el codigo me funciona perfecto salvo que me muestra error 404 not found si uso este codigo js desde una ibicacion en un directorio diferente "dominio.com/ofertas/descuento" por ejemplo , ahora bien: tengo mi JS que se activa desde el index, y envia los datos a /facebook/facebookusers.php y registra pero que pasa si el usuario esta en otra parte de la pagina, en otro directorio , digamos que esta en ofertas/deals , ... alli la ruta que tengo en mi $.POST de AJAX no me funciona

PREGUNTA , existe un método o forma para utilizar una ubicación "generica" para que desde cualquier ubicacion de la pagina el $.POST se envie correctamente

```
  function saveUserData(userData){
$.post('facebook/facebook-user.php', {oauth_provider:'facebook',userData: JSON.stringify(userData)}, function(data){ return true; }).done(function(data){
    reloadPage();
});
console.log(userData);
```

}

el codigo funciona bien si ejecuto desde index.php pero si la ubicacion cambia, es decir desde otra ubicacion ejemplo:ofertas.php me quiero loguear, no puedo hacerlo me tira error 404 not found. ya que no coincide la ruta

Answer (score 1):

Aun que no es una buena practica, puedes poner la ruta completa.

ejemplo: 
si lo que necesitas esta en una ruta así =  home->librerias->facebook->facebook-user.php

lo que puedes hacer es poner por ejemplo : "../librerias/facebook/facebook-user.php"

los puntos lo que hacen es volver niveles entre las carpetas/ubicaciones para poder poner una ruta diferente.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta corta es **SI, EXISTE** la respuesta larga contiene un par de opciones:

- **Rutas absolutas**: Puedes usar rutas absolutas y poner directo `$.post('https://www.midominio.com/carpeta/facebook/facebook-user.php',`. Esto tiene desventajas, principalmente que en ambientes de pruebas y producción seguramente cambian las URL's (aunque hay formas de resolverlo como modificando tu archivo de resolución de nombres de dominio). Adicionalmente el esquema de la ruta queda fijo: `http` vs `https`. Normalmente uno quiere que sus links sean independientes a esto.
- **Rutas relativas a la raíz del sitio**: Las rutas relativas a la raíz del sitio se consiguen con un solo punto como prefijo: `./`; lo puedes usar de la siguiente manera: `$.post('./carpeta/facebook/facebook-user.php` y es equivalente al link de la opción anterior.

Cuando usas como prefijo dos puntos `../` lo que le dices a tu browser es que la raíz de tu ruta es el directorio en el que se está ejecutando el script y que a partír de ahí tine que bajar n directorios para luego buscar la ruta que sufija a estos puntos.

Comment: puede usar `//www.midominio.com/carpeta/facebook/facebook-user.php` sin http o https